# Regular Expression with foreign languages

Tags: .net, regex, character-encoding, spoken-language

I have a function that I have used a bunch of times in various files which has a signature like:

```
Translate("English Message", "Spanish Message", "French Message")
```

and I am wanting to pull out the English, Spanish and French messages and then output them into a csv so that people who actually know these languages can tell me what I SHOULD have put in there.

Anyway, what I am running into is that some French and Spanish messages don't show up because of the accented characters and single quotes.

This is a vb.net program.

Edit

There was no problem with the language, my issue was actually the regular expression and my complete lack of understanding regular expressions.

Comment: What (programming) languages?

Comment: While you're at it, you should make the program *read* from these CSV files (or use a standard localization/globalization/whatever solution). Keeping translations in code is a very, very bad idea.

Comment: -1 for not specifying the environment/language in use. If you're not aware of UTF-8 and Unicode by now then it's time to learn.

Comment: @Daniel I am definitely moving these off to a file, but my thought was that I can make the translations in code and then change the method out for another that accessed a file instead.

Comment: @PP Thanks, it's good to see that people are understanding of people who NEVER deal with something and then ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the regex library you are using. Sane regex implementations use UTF-8 and have no such problems, but more details would be helpful about what lang you are using, what regex library etc.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a DOTALL flag in your language's regex implementation, you might want to set it.

Alternatively, change the regex to capture a negated character class instead, like so:

```
([^your_delimiter]*?)
```

with your_delimiter being the character(s) immediately succeeding the string that you want to capture.

See this for further discussion:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Unicode